# Powershell comparison for local network drive mappings against an array of drive mappings

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I'm developing a PowerShell script for company drive mapping purposes. Currently, the script is getting the logged in username and querying AD to store their groups. From there, we are going to compare their AD groups to an array (mappings) and then map their drives accordingly.

The problem is, we don't want to tamper with their current drive mappings *if* they are already mapped properly (they match the mappings array letter/path). I've tried doing a compare, looping, etc but I can't seem to find a good method to compare the currently mapped Network Drive Letter/Path to the array and if it's the same, to disregard it.

Essentially, we don't want to disconnect network drives if the current mapping matches what's in the array.

```
$mappings = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{adgroup='ADGROUP1';driveletter='G';networkpath='\\server\location1'}
    [pscustomobject]@{adgroup='ADGROUP2';driveletter='H';networkpath='\\server\location2'}
    [pscustomobject]@{adgroup='ADGROUP3';driveletter='I';networkpath='\\server\location3'}
    [pscustomobject]@{adgroup='ADGROUP4';driveletter='J';networkpath='\\server\location4'}
)

$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $env:username | select name

$currentDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object Name, DisplayRoot | Where-Object {$_.DisplayRoot -ne $null}

foreach ($mapping in $mappings) {
    if ($groups -match $mapping.adgroup) {
        Remove-PSDrive -Name $mapping.driveletter -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        New-PSDrive -Name $mapping.driveletter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $mapping.networkpath -Persist -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confusing because `Get-PSDrive H` will show the `Root` property being the network-mapped name.  But `(Get-PSDrive H).Root` will return `H:\`. Weird, right?
You can use the DisplayRoot property to get the *real* network share:

```
If((Get-PSDrive $mapping.driveletter).DisplayRoot -ne $mapping.networkpath){
    #un-map and re-map the drive
}
```